# Positive definiteness of the derivative of a real-valued positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Is the derivative of a real-valued positive definite matrix is also a real-valued positive definite matrix?

If that is not always the case, when it is guaranteed?

Comment: Is the derivative of a positive function always positive?

Comment: @TedShifrin, I don't think so.

Comment: Indeed, there are plenty of decreasing positive functions. Basically, the only guarantee is to assume the conclusion you want.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I didn't understand your comment about guarantee. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Simple example: A *constant* positive definite matrix has the zero matrix as its derivative, which is not positive definite.

Comment: I'm saying that the only hypothesis that guarantees that the derivative is positive definite is that condition itself. You must assume that hypothesis in order to conclude it.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Assume the hypothesis to guarantee that would be tautological, right?

Comment: Yes, precisely. :)